# How to create 4-dimensional textures?

Tags: opengl

**EDIT**

glTexcoord4f allows to specif four dimensions of a texture, but how do you create 4-dimensional textures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any real "meaning" to them. If you were using shaders, you can assign any meaning you want to them.

For example, in our game: we used the xy for the actual texcoords, the z for which texture to sample from, and the w (4th component) to control the brightness.

There is such thing as 3D and 4D textures which do actually require 3 and 4 texcoords respectively, I suppose that could be the "meaning" of them.

The main reason that they exist, is because graphics cards work with 4 component vectors. When you pass a 2D texcoord in, it's still a 4-vector behind the scenes (the other r and q components aren't set). OpenGL provides you with the functionality to use them, on the off chance that you might need it.

Comment: I understand the maths behind opengl, I have a degree in applied maths, I'm just asking whether the 4-th argument is a 4-th texture dimension? How do you create 4-dimensional textures then?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that it's whatever you want it to be (if using shaders). If you happen to be sampling from a 4 dimensional texture, then yes, it's the 4th texture dimension. I'm not sure how widely supported it is, but use this: http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/SGIS/texture4D.txt

Answer (score 4):

The *r* component is used to specify either the depth in a 3D (volumetric) texture, or the layer in a 2D texture array.

The *q* component plays the same role, like the vertex position *w* element: It is used for scaling the perspective divide in perspective texture projection.

Comment: So it means that the 4th coordinate is justs fourth texture dimension?

Comment: @Lu4: Not quite. Technically it's just another number. However – a little known fact – a homogenous coordinate divide is also applied on the texture coordinates (which are transformed by their very own texture matrix, BTW) by default in the fixed function pipeline. The actual mapping from texture coordinates to sampling coordinates depend on the active texture target and in the case of samplers on the sampling function used. Effectively the whole mapping of texture coordinates to sampling coordinates resembles the transformation process from vertices to normalized device (=window) coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The r component is the 3rd coordinate for GL_TEXTURE_3D (for rendering volumes). I am not familiar with any method that uses the 4th coordinate.

But it seems reasonable to have that available as all homogeneous OpenGL vectors have 4 components.

Comment: First coordinate is 'x', second coordinate is 'y', third coordinate is 'z'

Comment: but what does 4-th coordinate mean?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a 4-dimensional texture. At least, not without extensions.

The reason `glTexCoord4D` exists is to allow passing 4 values. In the modern shader-based rendering world, "texture coordinates" don't have to be texture coordinates at all. They're just values the shader uses to do whatever it does.

Many of the [texture lookup functions](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Sampler#Texture_lookup_functions) in shaders take more texture coordinate dimensions than the dimensionality of the actual texture. All texture functions for `shadow` textures take an extra coordinate, which represents the comparison value. All of the `Proj` texture functions take an extra coordinate, which represents the homogeneous coordinate for a [homogeneous coordinate system](http://Homogeneous%20coordinates).

In fixed-function land, 4D texture coordinates can be used for projective texturing of 3D textures. So the 4D coordinate is in a [homogeneous coordinate system](http://Homogeneous%20coordinates).